# How to load a file starting at a specific memory location or array

Tags: ruby

My work on a 6502 emulator is continuing. I've run into some quirks with the embedded processor emulation wherein I need to load a 6502 binary file in an array starting at 0x1000.

Of course, loading a file is easy. But the offset part is isn't. In C, I can do it easily.

Here's the code for loading a file I'm using right now:

```
  def loadbinary(filename)
    @prog = File.open(filen, "rb") { |io| io.read }
    @imagesize = @prog.size
  end
```

If the load is loaded at 0x1000, the preceding space can be empty (before 0x1000).

Any ideas?

For anyone interesting, this is for the [6502.rb project](https://github.com/farhany/6502) I have on GitHub

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to allocate an array of `n` bytes, where `n` is the size of addressable RAM you want to emulate. From there you can start storing your data read in from the file into "RAM".

This is what I'd start with:

```
def loadbinary(filename)
  @prog = File.read(filename, 'rb')
  @imagesize = @prog.bytesize
end

RAM_SIZE = 1024 * 64
RAM = Array.new(RAM_SIZE)

loadbinary('/path/to/foo')
RAM[0x1000, @imagesize] = @prog.bytes.to_a
```

Note: You can't use `String.size` to get the length of the string, because it allows for multibyte characters. Instead, to get the number of bytes, you need `bytesize`, which, according to [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-bytesize):

> Returns the length of str in bytes.

Similarly, we can't try to convert `@prog` into an array using `split('')` because that allows for multibyte characters too. Instead, we can get the bytes and turn that into an array. It could be done using `unpack` or `bytes.to_a`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't. `io.read` returns <strike>an array</strike> a string; it does not write to a pre-existing array.

You have to do the workaround of first reading into an array, then [splicing](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) into another array. Something like

```
progimage = io.read.bytes.to_a
image[start, progimage.size] = progimage
```

Luckily, pretty much any system now running Ruby has somewhat more memory and CPU power than C64, so using an extra array is not too much of a bother.

Comment: [`IO.read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-read) doesn't return an array, it returns what is effectively a String, but it's just a "string" full of bytes. The bytes could represent anything. `IO.read('/dev/null').class
=> String`

Comment: Doh, brain fart. Of course it doesn't return an `Array`... Let me rephrase. (And thanks for being watchful)